# Angular Pipe testing using RXJS

Tags: angular, testing, rxjs

Is it possible to force a specific error in angular for testing purposes using RXJS?

Example:

```
somerequest('http://myserversomewhere/endpoint').pipe(new Error(404, 'Endpoint Not Found'));
```

Instead of setting up a mock server somewhere and building out the whole set of errors to test

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mock an error, but first you should mock your service provider. Here an example:

```js
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

describe('Set of tests', () => {
  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: MyService, useClass: FakeMyService }
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('My first test', () => {
    myService = TestBed.get(MyService);

    // HERE IS WHERE WE SHOULD MOCK A SERVICE' FUNCTION
    spyOn(myService, 'myServiceFunction')
      .and.returnValue(throwError(new Error(404, 'Endpoint Not Found')));
  });

});
```

Full example on github: [here](https://github.com/danidelgadoz/ngx-admin/blob/master/src/app/dashboard/customer/customer-detail/customer-detail.component.spec.ts)

Comment: We used it in a service directly and swapped out the `new Error` for a `new HttpErrorResponse`, it allows for more return params for better debugging